# Stream Videos Online and Access Rights

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, video-streaming, flv

I have a web application that i have developed in `RoR 2.1`. In the app, users have the privilege of uploading media files. Currently, only FLV videos can be streamed online since i have given `FLV` player browser support.I have used the gem `Mime Types` to identify the file fomats of the media files being uploaded.

I would like to get the feasibility and ways to implement two new requirements

- How can i stream all videos being uploaded online? Should I convert these files  to flv or 
  is there any other way of making it possible?
- I want the users who upload the videos to set a privilege (count) of how many users can 
  stream this video on line at a given time. How can i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) for streaming you should use a CDN, this should not be the responsibility of your rails app.  Lots of options, I have enjoyed working with S3/Cloudfront.  Streaming through your app will really hurt the scalability of your platform.  Lets the good folks at the CDN deal with this.

2) To throttle the usage -- I would do the following.  When a web user wants to watch a video give them a link you your app (vs directly to the CDN) so `http://myapp/video/watch`.  In that method(VideosController#watch) you can count concurrent views, and if under the threshold then perform a secure redirect to the video.

---

If you must serve files directly from your server use `send_file` method ([doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html))

If you are looking for video playback, there a bunch of javascript/html5 video solutions:  VideoJS is a pretty good one: http://videojs.com/, It should be able to handle many different types of video formats
[enter link description here](http://videojs.com/)

Good luck

Comment: My app is already up and all the media files are stored on the server.. i want it to work as it is now with ideas of adding these functionalities to it!!

Comment: Updated my answer -- hope it points you in the right direction